# Where can I find a proof of the homeomorphic uniqueness of connected sum?

Tags: general-topology

For any two connected n-dimensional topological manifolds one can construct the connected sum of them, but how did I know it is well defined? Thanks for any reference.

Comment: Are you sure it's well-defined? You're not missing any words up there?

Comment: Indeed, we need oriented here, IIRC

Comment: Lee proves this result in his book [Introduction to Topological Manifolds](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/).

Comment: Yes. I negelect the oriented condition. But Lee's book only solve the surfaces case.

Comment: It's an exercise in Lee's _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_.